# How to add text next to links in OpenCart header

Tags: header, opencart

I am using OpenCart version 1.5.6. What I am trying to do, is put the time next to Checkout link in the header. The HTML time is an iframe code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="18" src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i3xbndy5/n2025/tlsi26" width="57"></iframe>
```

When I edit the header.tpl file, I can't seem to get it right, because the added time text does not slide the "links" elements to the left. I was playing with Firebug to see how this would look like, and adding text next to

```
<a href="http://domain.net/index.php?route=checkout/checkout">Checkout</a>
```

in `<div class="links">` shows up, but the border that separates links elements never shows up. Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe providing us with the link to Your site (with the iFrame active!) would be helpful (though unusual but necessary in this case I guess...).

Comment: The site address is http://www.plas.nazuka.net. You can see the time being displayed next to Checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Just put that iframe into an empty link:

```
<a href="#"><iframe ... /></a>
```

This will add the *left-border* and some *padding*, but I have no idea how to controll the font-size inside the iframe...

IMHO, completely useless approach - there are thousands of free JS scripts to give You the clock ability and You do not need to link a third-party website in an iframe that can harm Your site with advertisements or spyware...